# Good Twitter Extension Module for Magento

Tags: api, magento, rest, twitter, module

I'm wondering if there is an existing Twitter extension for Magento.  My needs for this module are probably somewhat unusual from what a Twitter extension would normally do in a Magento site.  Specifically, the only things I really care about are the models for interacting with Twitter's REST API.

Would be great if it supported things like:

- Native Magento collection getters, loaders, filters
- Ability to filter user twitter streams on hashtags
- Nice pagination support
- Nice-to-have would be the whole Twitter App Authentication piece.

From a quick search for "magento twitter extension", I found the [Lazymonks](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lazzymonks-twitter.html) one, which is compatible up to 1.3 (not encouraging), and the [Aheadwords](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/sociable.html) one, which I'm sure is solid, but isn't open source.

I'd love to find an open source extension that I could fork and contribute to as well.